# OpenSSL - Output PEM encoded part only when signing a certificate request

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

I've set up my own Certificate Authority based on a Debian 10 system and I can successfully sign certificates. But when I do so by using the command `openssl ca -in /root/ca/certreqs/domain.tld.csr -out /root/ca/certs/domain.tld.crt`, I'm getting a certificate file that includes both normal text as well as a PEM-encoded part.

This file's content starts with:

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        9b:fa:25:0d:[...]
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
[...]
```

And then there is the encoded part at the end (this is the only thing I want to be in this file):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE8TCCAtmgAwIBAgIRAJv6JQ0bTvBobRSX52Jl+AQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
QjELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxFzAVBgNVBAoMDkJlbm5ldCBSaWNodGVyMRowGAYDVQQD
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What do I have to do so that only the PEM-encoded part is in this file without removing the upper part manually (e.g. by using sed: `sed -ni '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,$p' /root/ca/certs/domain.tld.crt`)? I think there must be a parameter for this, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: `-notext` as per the man page on your system or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ca.html)

Comment: Thank you, I already tried this parameter but it didn't work (I don't know why). Then I thought this might be for another "text", but now I completely removed OpenSSL and installed it again (this time using the download on the OpenSSL website) and now it works, crazy... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To display only the certificate itself, I only do this:

```
openssl x509 -in /root/ca/certs/domain.tld.crt
```